# how to pick data in a ngx modal in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-modal

I'm trying to launch a ngx-modal when clicking a serie of `tr` in an angular table and pass data that the ngx-modal must work with. For each cicked `tr`, the modal must have different values passed in.

this is the method in the "main" .ts component that launches the modal:

```
  openModal(dummyItem) {
    const initialState = {
      clientId: dummyItem.clientId,
      clientName: dummyItem.clientName,
      facType: dummyItem.type,
      localCode: dummyItem.localCode,
      from: dummyItem.from,
      to: dummyItem.to,
      localName: dummyItem.localName,
      class: "modal-lg"
    };
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(DetalleFacturaPopUpComponent, {
      initialState,
      backdrop: "static",
      keyboard: false
    });
  }
```

in the main template, the method "openModal(dummyItem)" is attached to each `tr` as a `click` event using a `*ngFor`, so that for each row, the modal is launched with different data passed in, this way:

```
<tr *ngFor="let dummyItem of facturas" (click)="openDetalleFacturaAmpliado(dummyItem)" >
   <td>{{ dummyItem.numFac }}</td>
   <td class="text-center">{{ dummyItem.clientId}}</td>
   <td class="text-center">{{ dummyItem.clientName}}</td>
   <td class="text-center">{{ dummyItem.localCode}}</td>
   <td class="text-center">{{ dummyItem.localName}}</td>
   <td class="text-center">{{ dummyItem.from}}</td>
   <td class="text-center">{{ dummyItem.to}}</td>
   <td class="text-center">{{ dummyItem.type}}</td>
</tr>
```

The thing is that I don't know how to grab this data in the modal .ts file.

The following piece of code is from "DetalleFacturaPopUpComponent.ts", which is the component launched in from the first one:

```
export class DetalleFacturaPopUpComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(initialState.clientId)
}
```

but of course, this fails. "initialState" property is not recognized at all. I populated it in the main .ts as a but I can't manage to figure out how to grab it and use it.

I want to be able to fill a form (the template of the modal is a form) with the values of the properties of the variable "initialState" I passed in to the modal component,  but I can't manage to do it make use it... if I could at least console log one of the values, I could make the rest of the app I'm trying to develop.

May you help me figure out how can I make use of the data passed to the ngx-modal? Thanks.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz demo of your problem & share?

Comment: you can use the approach suggested in this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/50550901/8351493